# How to take X elements from a group by in C# lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to take the last 4 elements from a groupby and then add it to a List. I'm using MySQL as database and asp MVC5. I tried this:

```
List<Payments> payments= db.Payments
    .Where(e => e.Account.Active==true)
    .GroupBy(e => e.IdAccount)
    .Select(e => e.OrderBy(x => x.PaidDate).Take(4))
    .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

I got the following error:

> Unknown column 'Join2.IdAccount' in 'where clause'

This is the Payment class:

```
public partial class Payment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    [DisplayName("ID Account")]
    public int IdAccount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    [DisplayName("ID Client")]
    public int IdClient { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paid date")]
    public System.DateTime PaidDate { get; set; }


    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post the Payment class you are using

Comment: I think it is not so important, but well I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that it's MySQL provider (SQL expression creator) error. But, have you tried this way?

```
List<Payments> payments = db.Payments
    .Where(e => e.Account.Active == true)
    .GroupBy(e => e.IdAccount)
    .Select(e => e.OrderBy(x => x.PaidDate))
    .Take(4)
    .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

If this doesn't help you, you can always pass all query to code this way:

```
List<Payments> payments = db.Payments
    .Where(e => e.Account.Active == true)
    .GroupBy(e => e.IdAccount)
    .ToList() // From here all calculations will be on web server, not in SQL. So sql query will be simlier
    .Select(e => e.OrderBy(x => x.PaidDate))
    .Take(4)
    .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

But, it will affect perfomance.

Comment: Thank you, it worked that way, and you are right it is pretty slow. But well it is the problem to work with MVC and MySQL

Comment: MVC has absolutely nothing to do with this answer (or the question).

Comment: Yes it does, because sometimes the answer is in the web config or in an external reference. That's why I said I was using MVC5 and MySQL.